# catchError in interceptor eliminates ability to cancel request

Tags: angular

I have the request in some component that fires, for example, by click:

```
performRequest() {
    const request = this.http
      .get('https://randomfox.ca/floof/')
      .subscribe();

      request.unsubscribe();
}
```

And I have the http interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        return next.handle(req); // all is ok
        return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(e => throwError(e))); // request can't be cancelled now
    }
}
```

If first `return` is working - request is cancelled by `unsubscribe()` but with second - it is not cancelled (I'm talking about cancel on request level, like request is not pending but cancelled).

Why is it so and how to both handle errors in interceptor and have an ability to cancel requests?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your code example. Can you reproduce the issue with https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @cgTag https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z1uujx - I've tried on stackblitz and here it works fine, so probably somewhere in directly my app

Comment: Yeah, I saw nothing wrong with your code example and wasn't expecting it to be reproduced. It would have been a critical bug in Angular that impacts everyone. Search your source code for the `share()` operator, or any other operator that multicasts. Those operators interfere with cancelling. If you need to cancel and use share, then add a takeUntil() before the share.

Comment: @cgTag I have one more question - probably you have some ideas. I've slightly updated stackblitz - I've added timeout for 10 millis for the request and added console.log in `catchError` cb in interceptor - and when there is an timeout error, interceptor's catcher is not fired. Coud you please, tell, why it is so

Comment: It should be caught. Timeout throws an exception.

Comment: Yes, it should. But it isn't :)

Comment: @cgTag - I've asked about this on github and, they say, it is expected behavior https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28468#issuecomment-459517736

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some workaround, so it could probably help - 
`return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(noop, (err: any) => /* handle somehow*/));`

Also, want to mention, that I've tried it in separate (and +- clean) angular project and the issue was not reproduced

Comment: on stackblitz it also works fine - can't say why I'm encountering it in my codebase now

Comment: stackblitz (stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z1uujx) is cancelling all requests. Even those when unsubscribe is commented out of the code.